# Not able to download Kotlin plugin from eclipse marketspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-photon

I am using `Eclipse` Platform Version: `Photon` (4.8) as my IDE.
I want to use `kotlin` in the same IDE, so I was trying to get it from the market space. But I am not able to download it . I tried two options.

- My `Network Connection` Active Provider is `native` (window -> preferences -> Network Connections). I am able to find the Kotlin plugin but failed to download it saying that `Authentication is needed`.
- My `Network Connection` Active Provider is `manual`(window -> preferences -> Network Connections).I have provided the authentication details for `http` and `https`. Here I am not even able to open the market space.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started-eclipse.html) how to do that. Go to Eclipse Marketplace, search for Kotlin.

If that doesnt work, you can still try the "Install New Software" that will do the same as explained down bellow **.

[image]
[image]

** Another option is to drag and drop (this is like a shortcut for the option above), [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/kotlin-plugin-eclipse) are the steps, just be sure you have the Eclipse Marketplace Client like the print bellow indicates.If so, you just need to drag and drop the button to your Eclipse IDE and that's it, follow the steps, next, next, next...

[image]

---

Continuing:

Add this line 
`-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4`

to the end of your Eclipse `config.ini` and try again. Keep `Active Provider` Native. If it doesn't work, chance `Active Provider` to `Manual` and uncheck `Socks`, then try again.

After you copy and paste that line, please restart Eclipse (It starts with an '-' sign, just to be clear: `-Dorg.eclipse...`

If that doesn't work too, then the last option is to change `Active Provider` to `Direct` and try again.

Comment: I am doing the above steps, but the install is not getting complete. The error shown has been described in the question.

Comment: @JITHIN you don't need authentication to do what you want. I have never seen that behaviour. Are you behind a firewall or are you using a proxy? check my answer, updated it.